# XSLT-2.0 IF statement/grouping

Tags: xml, if-statement, xslt, grouping

I am new to XSLT and XML and was trying to create a CSV from an XML file using XSLT. I have a bunch of Faculty data regarding certain years they published different types of content such a as books, chapters in books, journal articles and so on, I would like to Ideally tabulate them to show the count of each type of publication each year Like so:

```
Year, 1990, 1993, 1995, 1994, .....2017, 2018
Book,  1,3,0,0,...1,1
Journal Article,  2,1,0,1,...1,1
Book Chapter, 1, 1,0,0,...0,0
```

As you can see, I would like to force a zero for the years that they don't have any of that particular type of publication. I am able to get it into a form where it plots them without the zeros, but for data purposes I would like to force it. Here is the format of our XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<Data xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2017-10-16">
    <Record userId="1898739" username="50019019" termId="5923" dmd:surveyId="17683692">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="COLLEGE" entryKey="College of Engineering" text="College of Engineering"/>
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="DEPARTMENT" entryKey="Civil, Architectural, &amp; Environmental Engineering" text="Civil, Architectural, &amp; Environmental Engineering"/>
        <INTELLCONT id="151368386560" dmd:originalSource="MANAGE_DATA" dmd:lastModified="2017-10-03T10:47:54" dmd:startDate="2016-01-01" dmd:endDate="2016-12-31">
            <REFEREED>Yes</REFEREED>
            <CONTYPE>Journal Article</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER/>
            <STATUS>Published</STATUS>
            <TITLE>Sample data</TITLE>
            <TITLE_SECONDARY/>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="151368386563">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="151368386561">
                <FACULTY_NAME>1898739</FACULTY_NAME>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME>sample</MNAME>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <PUBLISHER>sample</PUBLISHER>
            <PUBCTYST/>
            <PUBCNTRY/>
            <VOLUME>13</VOLUME>
            <ISSUE>11</ISSUE>
            <PAGENUM>117</PAGENUM>
            <WEB_ADDRESS/>
            <DOI>sample</DOI>
            <ISBNISSN/>
            <PMCID/>
            <AUDIENCE/>
            <PUBLICAVAIL/>
            <ABSTRACT/>
            <FULL_TEXT/>
            <DTM_EXPSUB/>
            <DTD_EXPSUB/>
            <DTY_EXPSUB/>
            <EXPSUB_START></EXPSUB_START>
            <EXPSUB_END></EXPSUB_END>
            <DTM_SUB/>
            <DTD_SUB/>
            <DTY_SUB/>
            <SUB_START></SUB_START>
            <SUB_END></SUB_END>
            <DTM_ACC/>
            <DTD_ACC/>
            <DTY_ACC/>
            <ACC_START></ACC_START>
            <ACC_END></ACC_END>
            <DTM_PUB/>
            <DTD_PUB/>
            <DTY_PUB>2016</DTY_PUB>
            <PUB_START>2016-01-01</PUB_START>
            <PUB_END>2016-12-31</PUB_END>
            <USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>Yes</USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>
        </INTELLCONT>
        <INTELLCONT  dmd:originalSource="IMPORT" dmd:lastModified="2017-10-03T11:17:33" dmd:startDate="2016-01-01" dmd:endDate="2016-12-31">
            <REFEREED>Yes</REFEREED>
            <CONTYPE>Journal Article</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER/>
            <STATUS>Published</STATUS>
            <TITLE>Sample</TITLE>
            <TITLE_SECONDARY/>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756225">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756226">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756227">
                <FACULTY_NAME>1898739</FACULTY_NAME>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME>sample</MNAME>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756228">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME>sample</MNAME>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756229">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756230">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>sample</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756231">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756232">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756233">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME>sample</MNAME>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756234">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <INTELLCONT_AUTH id="141176756235">
                <FACULTY_NAME/>
                <FNAME>sample</FNAME>
                <MNAME/>
                <LNAME>sample</LNAME>
                <INSTITUTION/>
                <ROLE>Author</ROLE>
                <STUDENT_LEVEL/>
            </INTELLCONT_AUTH>
            <PUBLISHER>sample</PUBLISHER>
            <PUBCTYST/>
            <PUBCNTRY/>
            <VOLUME>23</VOLUME>
            <ISSUE/>
            <PAGENUM>2003-2013</PAGENUM>
            <WEB_ADDRESS/>
            <DOI>sample</DOI>
            <ISBNISSN/>
            <PMCID/>
            <AUDIENCE/>
            <PUBLICAVAIL/>
            <ABSTRACT/>
            <FULL_TEXT/>
            <DTM_EXPSUB/>
            <DTD_EXPSUB/>
            <DTY_EXPSUB/>
            <EXPSUB_START></EXPSUB_START>
            <EXPSUB_END></EXPSUB_END>
            <DTM_SUB/>
            <DTD_SUB/>
            <DTY_SUB/>
            <SUB_START></SUB_START>
            <SUB_END></SUB_END>
            <DTM_ACC/>
            <DTD_ACC/>
            <DTY_ACC/>
            <ACC_START></ACC_START>
            <ACC_END></ACC_END>
            <DTM_PUB/>
            <DTD_PUB/>
            <DTY_PUB>2016</DTY_PUB>
            <PUB_START>2016-01-01</PUB_START>
            <PUB_END>2016-12-31</PUB_END>
            <USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>Yes</USER_REFERENCE_CREATOR>
        </INTELLCONT>
    </Record>            <!-- Added by edit -->
</Data>                  <!-- Added by edit -->
```

All of the confidential information has been replaced with the word "sample" for obvious reasons but this should not effect the logic. So My current XSLT is printing all of the years and then followed by the type of article like so:

```
Type
Journal Article,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,
,1,3,3,1,2,1,2,3,8,2,12,11,5,6,10,11,4,5,4,7,10,4,

Book,1995,2006,2008,2011,
,1,1,1,1,

Book Chapter,2005,2006,2008,2011,2015,2016,
,1,3,3,2,1,1,

Abstract,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,
,8,22,12,6,13,9,6,18,5,3,4,2,7,1,

Other,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,
,2,3,2,2,8,

Total,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,
,1,1,3,3,1,2,1,2,3,25,38,34,19,31,17,17,32,10,8,8,11,19,6,
```

And here is the XSLT-2.0 for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csv="csv:csv"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:dm="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data"
    xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" exclude-result-prefixes="array fn map math xhtml xs">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>
    <!-- xmlns:dm is the xmlns attribute in Data.-->

    <xsl:template match="/dm:Data">
        <xsl:text>Type</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>        
        <!--Journal Article Publications-->
        <xsl:text>Journal Article,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[dm:CONTYPE='Journal Article']" group-by="dm:DTY_PUB">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="(current-grouping-key())" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[dm:CONTYPE='Journal Article']" group-by="dm:DTY_PUB">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <!-- Book Publications -->
        <xsl:text>Book,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[dm:CONTYPE='Book']" group-by="dm:DTY_PUB">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="(current-grouping-key())" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[dm:CONTYPE='Book']" group-by="dm:DTY_PUB">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <!--Book Chapter Publications-->
        <xsl:text>Book Chapter,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[dm:CONTYPE='Book Chapter']" group-by="dm:DTY_PUB">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="(current-grouping-key())" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[dm:CONTYPE='Book Chapter']" group-by="dm:DTY_PUB">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <!--Abstract Publications-->
        <xsl:text>Abstract,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[dm:CONTYPE='Abstract']" group-by="dm:DTY_PUB">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="(current-grouping-key())" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[dm:CONTYPE='Abstract']" group-by="dm:DTY_PUB">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <!--Other Publications-->
        <xsl:text>Other,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[dm:CONTYPE='Other']" group-by="dm:DTY_PUB">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="(current-grouping-key())" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT[dm:CONTYPE='Other']" group-by="dm:DTY_PUB">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>Total,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT" group-by="dm:DTY_PUB">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="(current-grouping-key())" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT" group-by="dm:DTY_PUB">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So I am thinking I need to include some sort of If statement in the code in order to just print all the years and then force a zero for years that a certain type of publication does not exist.

Here is some sort of pseudo code of what the logic sounds like to me:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT" group-by="dm:DTY_PUB">
  <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" /> 
  <xsl:if test = "dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT/dm:CONTYPE != 'Book'">  //if the type of content is not of Book, print zero for that year
                    print ("0,")    
             else: <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" /> <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> // otherwise, print the number of Books published that year.     
  </xsl:if> 
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Please let me know if my question is unclear.
I spent a good amount of time trying to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: Consider this comment to just be a comment: I don't see any use in converting the XML to a worse format like CSV. Why don't you convert it to [XML-TEI P5](http://www.tei-c.org/Guidelines/P5/) instead. For me, this would be a lot more logical, because TEI is designed especially for annotating scientific text in a standardized format.

Comment: @zx485 While I agree with you 100% and have tried convincing the department to go about it in a different manner, they already have a system in place and I must adhere to their format.

Comment: Yeah. Got that. Business logic *TRUMP*s other logic \*gg\* :-(

Comment: @zx485 exactly, no amount of me whining is going to make a difference. Do you happen to know how I can go about this properly?

Comment: I will see what I can do.

Comment: @zx485 Much appreciated

Comment: I started to remember: you have asked this or a very similar question yesterday or the day before. Its answer is way to complex for a single SO question. And I dare to remember that you haven't made any progress with this. The output of my test case is still far away from an answerable question.

Comment: @zx485 Yeah I posted the question but I did a poor job asking it in a clear manner and posting incomplete XML code. So are you saying its not possible in XSLT? or that you just arent sure how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess we don't need all those elements in the sample, it sounds you have one child element giving the type or category to group by and you have a year. So I have created some simpler sample data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <items>
        <item>
            <category>a</category>
            <year>2000</year>
        </item>
        <item>
            <category>a</category>
            <year>2017</year>
        </item>
        <item>
            <category>a</category>
            <year>2000</year>
        </item>
        <item>
            <category>b</category>
            <year>1999</year>
        </item>
        <item>
            <category>b</category>
            <year>2018</year>
        </item>
        <item>
            <category>b</category>
            <year>1999</year>
        </item> 
        <item>
            <category>b</category>
            <year>2000</year>
        </item> 
    </items>
</root>
```

and an XSLT 3 stylesheet (can be run with Saxon 9.8 all editions) using a composite key to allow identifying a group of items by category and year. The list of years is simply created using the `min` and `max` functions. So with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:key name="cat-year" match="items/item" composite="yes" use="category, xs:integer(year)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="input-doc" select="."/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="min-year" as="xs:integer" select="min(root/items/item/year/xs:integer(.))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="max-year" as="xs:integer" select="max(root/items/item/year/xs:integer(.))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="categories" select="distinct-values(root/items/item/category)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="years" as="xs:integer*" select="$min-year to $max-year"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$years" separator=","/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="$categories">
            <xsl:variable name="cat" select="."/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$years!count(key('cat-year', ($cat, .), $input-doc))" separator=","/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get

```
1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018
a
0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
b
2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
```

Try to adapt that to your XML format. Let us know whether you can use XSLT 3 or are stuck with XSLT 2, in that case you could define a key concatenating the category and year and the rest of the code should work the same:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:key name="cat-year" match="items/item" use="concat(category, '|', year)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="input-doc" select="."/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="min-year" as="xs:integer" select="min(root/items/item/year/xs:integer(.))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="max-year" as="xs:integer" select="max(root/items/item/year/xs:integer(.))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="categories" select="distinct-values(root/items/item/category)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="years" as="xs:integer*" select="$min-year to $max-year"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$years" separator=","/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="$categories">
            <xsl:variable name="cat" select="."/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="for $y in $years return count(key('cat-year', concat($cat, '|', $y), $input-doc))" separator=","/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Gonna test this and get back to you, Im not sure if theyre allowing XSLT 3 but its worth a shot.

Comment: This was perfect thank you so much it worked like a charm, I used XSLT V2 cause I think they limited me to that but you helped me so much, forever grateful! Gonna post my solution below

Answer (score 1):

@Martin Honnen  posted a solution that worked perfectly, I took it and applied it to my own problem and here is the code in case anyone would like to see how it applies to mine specifically:

```
<xsl:key name="Contype-Year" match="dm:Data/dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT" use="concat(dm:CONTYPE, '|', dm:DTY_PUB)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="input-doc" select="."/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="min-year" as="xs:integer" select="min(dm:Data/dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT/dm:DTY_PUB/xs:integer(.))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="max-year" as="xs:integer" select="max(dm:Data/dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT/dm:DTY_PUB/xs:integer(.))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="categories" select="distinct-values(dm:Data/dm:Record/dm:INTELLCONT/dm:CONTYPE)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="years" as="xs:integer*" select="$min-year to $max-year"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$years" separator=","/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="$categories">
            <xsl:variable name="cat" select="."/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="for $y in $years return count(key('Contype-Year', concat($cat, '|', $y), $input-doc))" separator=","/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```